# Overwrite Sonar Test Task Gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

```
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'

sonarqube {
  properties {
    property 'x','x'
  }
}

subprojects {
  test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'IT'
    }
  }

  task testIT(type: Test) {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTestIT.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
    useTestNG() {
        includeGroups 'IT'
    }
  }
}
```

I have two tasks currently and in my Jenkins build we have one job that just runs the unit tests and another task that runs *testIT* task. I want to be able to call the sonarqube command to upload the information to our sonarqube instance. This works but when I call *./gradlew clean testIT sonarqube* all of the unit tests run again. Is there a way I can compile and upload only the sonar results for task *test* and *testIT* individually? Ultimately I don't want *./gradlew clean testIT sonarqube* to run the unit tests as well as the integration tests. Maybe this can be done with a separate task or maybe I can overwrite the test task that sonarQube uses?

Comment: Maybe it's crystal clear to others, but I've read the last part of your question three times and it's not clear to me what you want to happen versus what is happening. Could you rephrase "compile and upload only the sonar results for task test and testIT individually"?

Comment: If I run *./gradlew sonarqube* it appears to run the tests as a dependency. I really want to be able to run "./gradlew test sonarqube" and have it compile the code coverage for just the unit tests and upload them to sonar and then run the task "./gradlew testIT sonarqube" and have that run just the integration tests and upload just that information to sonar. Currently when I run "./gradlew testIT sonarqube" it is also running the regular unit tests also.

Comment: With the new sonarqube plugin is it possible to make a new gradle task that doesn't depend on test but rather depends on task "testIT" and then I can call the new sonar task whenever I run integration tests?

Comment: You might expand your question with the answers you've provided in comments @Derek...